# Ubuntu 12.04 Freezes after removing the HDMI cable or changing settings

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I'm using an fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm having some problems with HDMI. I usually use it with my TV, but since the update isn't working any more.

Sometimes in 11.10 I had to execute a script to get the video and sound to work in HDMI, but it was OK. Since the update, when I connect the HDMI cable, it works, but if I make any change in the display settings (like resolution, monitor position, etc,) it freezes.

And if I don't change anything, it's working in both monitors, but when I remove the cable, it freezes and even the ctrl+alt+f2 shortcut works.

Any ideas for fixing this?
I Googled and only found many people having problems, usually with sound.

Comment: Trying to fix and I discovered something:
When the "display monitor" window is on the laptop screen (screen 1), it works, but if it's on the secondary monitor, it freeze everything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: Question is 5+ years old with no answers. 12.04 is EOL. VTC as `not reproducible`.